# How was this equation for finding current written?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-analysis, inductor

It doesn't make any sense because at \$t\gt 0\$ the two circuits are disconnected (the left and right portion).

How has \$25 i_x\over 20\$ been calculated?

[image]

Comment: When the switch opens, the 10mF capacitor will start discharging through the 75R + 25R resistors.

Comment: @brhans okay but I still don't understand why they divided 25ix by 20

Comment: I also don't get how they wrote the KVL equation , Why use the 100 ohm resistance with every current?

Comment: 100 is a 'common' factor, you could just rewire it as: 34=125ix-80ix+100ix+25ix, text book writers seem to like taking out every possible common factor even when it makes the equation less intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they have been disconnected but in the instant after the switch is opened (t = 0+), the branch containing the capacitor still maintains its voltage (due to stored capacitor charge) and so the voltage across the 25-ohm resistor remains the same and the current through it \$i_x\$ also remains the same, so that it seems, from the perspective of the right half of the circuit, that nothing has changed; the switch isn't open yet!

So \$i_x(0+)\$ can be calculated using the circuit's state as it was before the switch was opened. Of course, after a while, that current will drop to nothing as the capacitor completely discharges.

Comment: So we are using the 25 Ix Voltage to calculate the current through 20 ohm left circuit for t>0 ?

Comment: @Maya You need the 20-ohm resistor to derive an equation for the whole circuit. The source voltage 34 V is equal to the sum of the voltage across the 100-ohm resistor and the voltage across those parallel branches. To get the voltage across the 100-ohm resistor, you need the current that passed through it \$i_s\$. To get this current, you need to add the separate currents that flowed into each parallel branch, since together they all make up \$i_s\$. That is why you need the current through the 20-ohm branch.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by summing currents at the upper node. For \$t<0\$, the capacitor is fully charged and its current is zero, so that branch can be ignored. Let \$v\$ be the voltage at this node. By KCL, the currents sum to zero:
$$
0=\frac{34-v}{100}-\frac{v}{20}+0.8i_x-\frac{v}{25}
$$
where the first term is the current into the node through the 34V source, the 2nd term is the current through the 20 ohm resistor, etc.  Noticing that \$v\$ is related to \$i_x\$ by
$$
v=25 i_x
$$
we can substitute for \$v\$:
$$
0=\frac{34-25i_x}{100}-\frac{25i_x}{20}+0.8i_x-\frac{25i_x}{25}
$$
So, \$25i_x/20\$ represents the current through the 20 ohm resistor.  Re-arranging and simplifying we get:
$$
\frac{34}{100} = 0.25i_x + 1.25i_x-0.8i_x+i_x
$$
Now you can see why everything on the right side is multiplied by 100. Collect terms and solve for \$i_x\$

At \$t>0\$ the left and right sides are not really disconnected, because the current source on the left side is dependent on the current through the 25 ohm resistor, which is now being supplied by the discharging capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

The equation looks like \$i_x(0^-)\$, not \$i_x(0^+)\$

For \$t=0^-\$, let \$V\$ be the node voltage at the closed switch. Note that C is fully charged, hence current through C and the 75 resistor is zero.

Due to \$i_x\$ through the 25 resistor, \$V=25i_x\$

Then nodal analysis gives:
$$\frac{V-34}{100}+\frac{V}{20}-0.8i_x+i_x=0$$

Multiplying through by 100 and letting \$V=25i_x\$:
$$25i_x-34+125i_x-80i_x+100i_x=0$$
$$170i_ x=34$$
Hence $$i_x(0^-)=\frac{34}{170}=0.2A$$

The voltage across the fully charged C must be \$V=25i_x=5\$ since there is no current through the 75 resistor and no drop across it, hence the current through the series\$ (25+75)\$ resistors when the switch is opened is $$i_x(0^+)=\frac{5}{100}=0.05A$$.

The circuit to the left of the switch has no effect on \$i_x(0^+)\$ since there is no dependent source to the right of the switch.